# In ISP network when assign my own Static IP to Network adapter Why I am not able to ping even nearest router

Tags: ip, wide-area-network, isp, pppoe

My ISP uses pppoe to authenticate and allocate ip to my machine but when assign my own Static  IP to Network adapter Why  I am disconnected from network or not able to ping even nearest router 
What kind of mechanism my ISP uses to machine don't have Access to the  Network

Comment: Your question is unclear. You assign a public IP to your server and you want to ping LAN gear ? kinda normal it fail

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your ISP configures their network equipment according to PPPoE authentication. Only PPPoE authenticated users have access to the network, other IP packets are dropped.

When you change to a static IP, the PPPoE session ends and your ISP's router starts dropping all traffic from your end.

Comment: You actually got my Question how does the process of Droping packets Work 
any way I could Bypass that

Comment: Your ISP has designed its network this way and it is their policy that only authenticated users have access. You need to contact your ISP about this. Serverfault people will not answer questions on how to circumvent policy.

Comment: I know there is a mechanism 
a Specific name of the Mechanism Would be great

Comment: @PratikKhadtale, the mechanism is part of AAA (Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting). If you have not been authenticated, you will not be authorized.

Answer (score 0):

you are using router to dial to pppoe? Or OS, modem?? If the machine picks up such Request Package it answers with an ICMP Echo Reply. If you turn off "Ping from WAN" you simply tell your router that it should not care about any ICMP Echo Requests sent to you. If you have router, check whether you have disabled ping from WAN in router.